# Alternate checked between buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to alternate if a button is checked. I've come up with this, which works but its feels unnecessary to write 70 lines of code for such a simple task.

How would I go about to shorten this up, is there any way I can call the base `toolStripButton` and tell it to uncheck other buttons when clicked on and check it self?

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton3.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton4.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton5.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton6.Checked = false;
    }
}
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton1.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton3.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton4.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton5.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton6.Checked = false;
    }
}

private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton3.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton1.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton4.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton5.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton6.Checked = false;
    }
}

private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton4.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton3.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton1.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton5.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton6.Checked = false;
    }

}

private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton5.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton3.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton1.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton4.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton6.Checked = false;
    }
}

private void toolStripButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton6.Checked == true)
    {
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton3.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton1.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton5.Checked = false;
        toolStripButton4.Checked = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You do know this is how RadioButton works out of the box.  And is how a user would expect  a RadioButton to work.

Comment: There are no RadionButtons [available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2006/04/24/radio-buttons-on-a-menustrip/) in a ToolStrip.

Comment: Gather all the buttons in a list. Write a single event handler and register it with all those buttons. In the handler, `foreach` thusly: `nextButton.Checked(nextButton.Equals(sendingButton))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this can easily be achieved with a few non-redundant lines.

You can [hook up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161) all button clicks to this **common** `MouseDown` event:

```
private void toolStripButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripButton button = sender as ToolStripButton;
    if (button == null) throw new InvalidCastException();
    foreach (ToolStripItem item in button.Owner.Items)
    {   
        if (item is ToolStripButton)
        {
            ((ToolStripButton)item).Checked = (item == button);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Click` event doesn't allow you to find out which button was clicked as all button clicks map to the `ToolStrip` itself! Therefore it doesn't lend itself to any sort of common processing that makes use of the `sender` paramter all events have..

As ever so often `MouseDown` works much better ;-)

The logic above assumes you want a radiobutton-like behaviour. `RadioButtons` can only be switched `on`; to switch them `off` you need to click another `RadioButton` in the group. If you want to be able to switch a button `on` and `off` directly you can expand it a little..

Comment: If you only had put more of `{}` there I'd give you a +1 ;-P

Comment: Well, either two or none ;-)

Comment: Agreed on both points. Well, this answer was moved here from SO, where it is quite normal to leave out all sorts of checks without warning and write out only the bare solution to the core issue, not perfeced code.. But since we are here now..

Comment: Why make a soft-cast only to throw an `InvalidCastException` manually when the `as` cast evaluates to `null`? Seems simply casting `(ToolStripButton)sender` would do the same thing with a little less boilerplate.

Comment: Hm, not sure I agree; this is a message to the developer and an invitation to expand it according to one's policy, like sending a custom message, like 'Only hook this up to ToolStripButtons!'.. Simply letting the exception happen can't ever be a good idea, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Simply collect all the buttons in a list, and then you can use a single event handler for all the check buttons:

```
private List<ToolStripButton> buttons = new List()
{
    toolStripButton1,
    toolStripButton2,
    toolStripButton3,
    toolStripButton4,
    toolStripButton5,
    toolStripButton6
};

private void toolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // skip if the current button is not checked
    if (!((ToolStripButton)sender).Checked)
        return;

    // loop through all buttons and uncheck them
    foreach (var btn in buttons)
    {
        // do not uncheck current button
        if (btn != sender)
            btn.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two answers, both missing `{}`...  conspiracy? ;-)

Comment: Well, I do have some… :P And I think my answer was first, so obviously TaW copied that from me!!! :D ;D